# How to set onActivityResulton kotlin after taking picture with "The following declarations have the same JVM signature" error?

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

I am trying to set the onActivityResult on a kotlin class after a picture is taken or attached from the local files. The java code is working fine

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CameraService.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            photoList.add(mPhotoFile.toString());
        }
    }else{
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            photoList.add(picturePath);
        }
    }
}
```

But on a kotlin class, that same block of code gives me an error "The following declarations have the same JVM signature"

This is the kotlin code

```
private fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        if (requestCode == CameraService.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                photoList.add(mPhotoFile.toString())
            }
        } else {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val selectedImage = data.data
                val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                val cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null)
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
                val picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                cursor.close()
                photoList.add(picturePath)
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is [image: The following declarations have the same JVM signature]

Any help or suggestion would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code like

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        if (requestCode == CameraService.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                photoList.add(mPhotoFile.toString())
            }
        } else {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val selectedImage = data.data
                val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                val cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null)
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
                val picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                cursor.close()
                photoList.add(picturePath)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That did it, just had to put null check on the intent "data: Intent?".

Answer (score 0):

In fragment *onActivityResult* method, *data* parameter is nullable, so you must use `data: Intent?` :

```
private fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    // your code here
}
```